# Django FileBrowseField upload form

Tags: django, django-grappelli, django-filebrowser

I have an Artwork and ArtworkPhoto models in Django.
ArtworkPhoto has an FK to the Artwork and stores some additional data on the photo.

```
class ArtworkPhoto(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Omschrijving', blank=True)
   photo = FileBrowseField("Image", max_length=200, directory="artwork/",
                        extensions=[".jpg", ".png"], blank=False, null=False)
   artwork = models.ForeignKey(Artwork, null=False, verbose_name='kunstwerk')
```

Every Artwork has X photos, all working fine. 
Now I want to provide authenticated visitors with an upload form to add an artwork and photo's.

How can I save a posted file to the ArtworkPhotoModel? It's a Grapelli FileBrowser > Filebrowsefield ...

Thanks, i'm a bit stuck here. ...

Comment: a custom save function would do the trick

Comment: how can I save the images into the Artwork FileBrowseField? Custom save seems obvious :)